# Load utilizando Target

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

Estou tentando realizar refresh somente em parte do conteúdo, sendo assim, quero utilizar o Jquery com método Load. Porém gostaria que utilizar dentro do LI do código HTML o data-target="nome" e o load ser carregado através do Target. Existe a possibilidade ?

Segue código HTML:

```
   <nav id="sidebar" class="text-white">
     <div class="nome-do-usuario border-bottom ">
       <h5 class="text-center">Apoio Operacional</h5>
     </div>
     <ul class="lista-de-opcoes">
       <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#materiais" class="opcoes-principais text-left"><a href="#">Estoque</a>
         <ul class="submenu collapse" id="materiais">
           <li class="opcao"><a href="#">Cadastro de produtos</a></li>
           <li class="opcao"><a href="#">Entrada</a></li>
           <li class="opcao"><a href="#">Saída</a></li>
           <li class="opcao"><a href="#">Solicitar material</a></li>
           <li class="opcao"><a href="#">Gerenciar estoque</a></li>
         </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </nav>
   <div class="container-fluid" id="resposta-do-conteudo">
```

Segue código Jquery:

```
$('.submenu li').click(function(){
 $('#resposta-do-conteudo').load()
})
```

Gostaria que o LI ficasse assim: `<li class="opcao" data-target="cadastro-de-produtos.html"><a href="#">Cadastro de produtos</a></li>`

Oque colocar dentro do load() ?

Obrigado !!!

Answer (score 0):

Olá, o método *load* do jquery é uma forma bastante simples de buscar dados do servidor e atribuí-los a um elemento html, nele basta fornecer o endereço url de destino da página que você deseja carregar ao elemento.

Em seu caso este endereço url (ou parte dele) esta dentro da propriedade **data-target**, por tanto você precisa recuperar este valor do objeto e passar no método *load*. O resultado seria esse:

```
$('.submenu li').click(function() {
    const link = $(this).data('target');
    const baseUrl = 'http://localhost/pages/';
    $('#resposta-do-conteudo').load(baseUrl + link)
});
```

Observe que há uma variável chamada **baseUrl**, preencha ela com a url base da sua aplicação para que a busca seja bem sucedida. Estou supondo que todas as páginas que você deseja abrir estejam dentro do mesmo diretório, por exemplo:
- pages/cadastro-de-produtos.html
- pages/entrada.html

Você pode consultar mais sobre o funcionamento do método load no endereço https://api.jquery.com/load/